# error : 'classA' doesnot exist in current context

Tags: c#, winforms, class, reference

I started new project of Windows Forms. First page is `UserLogin`. in form load event I am taking the logintable from database into memory.
I am using a class in which all read and write operations methods are stored.

when I am calling the class in formload event, the error comes "doesnot exist in current context"

I may be missing some references or headerfilename..

Please Help
Thanks in Advance

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using System.Configuration;
   using System.Web;

   namespace InvestmentAndReturns
  {
public partial class UserLogin : Form
{
    public UserLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CenterToScreen();
    }

    public string UserID = null;
    private string userPass = null;
    public string UserGroup = null;
    DataTable UserLoginTable;
    int logintry = 1;
    public bool LoginStatus = false;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtUserID.Select();

        string cmd = "Select * from UserLogin";
        UserLoginTable = DbRdRw.SqlDbRead(cmd, "UserLogin");
    }
```

DbRdRw: this is the Class
SqlDbRead: this is read method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have included that class by directly pasting it in the project folder and then opened solution and then included in the project

It looks like you have copy pasted source file containing definition of `DbRdRw` from some other project - which mostly means the `namespace` declaration in the file will be from older project.

Things will work if you change the namespace to your current project `InvestmentAndReturns`.

However, why are you copy pasting this around? You could make a library dll for your `DbRdRw` and reference the  dll. That way you will keep your source code at one place.